# Obtaining 12 V from a 20-250 V DC source

Tags: power-supply, dc-dc-converter

I need to get 12 V DC from a high voltage source. The high voltage comes from a wind turbine. The voltage level changes randomly according to the wind speed. Its voltage can go up to 250 V DC. This 12 V DC will be used to run the control circuits at the start-up only; the main power will be supplied from an integrated SMPS unit as soon as the overall system starts working.

I designed the following circuit for this purpose:

[image]

I thought that directly dropping 250 V to 12 V would be risky and make the system unstable, so I decided to drop it down to an intermediate voltage level (i.e.; 60 V) first.

Is there a better (and as simple as this) way of doing this?

Comment: Is it a DC generator? What is the frequency? 50mA for 250V is pretty high current. The upper transistor will dissipate almost 10W in the worst case. There is no 100nF electrolytic capacitors. Maybe you mean 100uF?

Comment: @johnfound It is an AC generator. I think the frequency will be depending on the rotational speed of the rotor; which will depend on speed of the wind. That capacitor is not electrolytic; I just put that "+" mark for easily finding the corresponding pin on the PCB.

Comment: Will the current be turned off after startup?

Comment: @starblue Yes .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The schematic is generally speaking, working. But there are some points that need some clearing:

1. The rectifier circuit is important and have to be designed to work in whole frequency range of the generator.
2. The power dissipated from the upper transistor (in worst case) is: 190V*50mA=9.5W. For lower transistor: 2.4W; It is not something not seen, but it will need not very small heat sink in all cases. In my opinion you should think about making the consumption lower. If you can lower the current consumed to 5mA, the transistors will not need heat sinks at all.
3. Another possible approach is to use small accumulator battery for the start-up process and to charge it when everything works. This way the efficiency of the system can be higher, and considering the size of the heat sinks, the size smaller.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a better (and as simple as this) way of doing this?

Yes, and here's how I'd do it: -

- if it's AC then you need to rectify and add a smoothing capacitor.
- Using an emitter follower and zener to produce an output voltage limited to 120 VDC
- Use an LTC3639 buck regulator to convert the 120 VDC limited voltage to 12 V

[image]

For stage 1, adopt a similar approach to the original proposal - a high voltage BJT, 47 k\$\Omega\$ resistor and 120 V zener. Feed the emitter output to the buck regulator circuit shown above. At voltages lower than 120 V, the output won't fall away to nothing - it'll stay close to the incoming voltage minus a couple of volts under load.

The main advantage is that when the rectified supply is 250 V, current consumption is much smaller than 50 mA and hence the BJT isn't going to be frying. With the Buck supply limited to 120 VDC and with an output load current of 50 mA, the input current is going to be 5 mA + the current due to buck-inefficiences.

From the graph above, the buck power loss is about 50 mW at an output current of 50mA. So the input current will be 5mA + \$\frac{50mW}{120V}\$ = 5.4 mA.

If the BJT is dropping 130 V (250 VDC in, 120 VDC out) then its power will be 702 mW and a lot easier to find a heatsink for (possibly won't need one).

Maybe there are buck regulators that are capable of higher input voltages?

**EDIT** Why is the method I propose simpler? The original proposal uses a BJT, a resistor and a zener to reduce the main incoming voltage to a working level. Ditto my proposal. The buck regulator I propose uses 6 components whereas the original proposal uses 5 components but needs a heatsink and, depending where the circuit is fitted, possibly a fan. Is my proposal better? That's a matter of opinion.